# Triggering KeyEvents Not Working

Tags: android, keyevent

In my currentactivity I have been trying to trigger a keyevent using the following code:

```
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

This is the only code I call within my method.

but when this part of the code runs nothing happens and it doesn't simulate the back button being pressed. Before people recommend finish() or onBackPressed(), they will not work for my required implementation because I need both the home button and the recents button to be triggered too and that apparently can be done by triggering keyevents.

Anyone know whats going wrong here?

EDIT: I added:

```
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

to release the key and this worked but it wont work for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME or KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH. Do I need to declare permissions in my manifest to perform these?

Comment: I think simulating the event is more than that. According to the key events of android, "Each key press is described by a sequence of key events. A key press starts with a key event with ACTION_DOWN. If the key is held sufficiently long that it repeats, then the initial down is followed additional key events with ACTION_DOWN and a non-zero value for getRepeatCount(). The last key event is a ACTION_UP for the key up. If the key press is canceled, the key up event will have the FLAG_CANCELED flag set."

Comment: show you code, then probably people are in better position to help you out

Comment: I did show my code. I am literally calling just that method